# How to define text in node in a tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following piece of code.

I want to add text to my nodes by simply adding the text between the ampersand symbols. What is the syntax to do this?

For example I try to add the text "John Doe" in the 1st row of the second column. The text must contain a line break between John and Doe. The usual syntax I would use would be something like:

`\node[draw, align = center]{John \\ Doe};`

How would do this in a matrix in which I predefined the nodes in the matrice's options?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(a)[matrix of nodes , nodes in empty cells , nodes = {draw , circle , align = center} ,
column sep={1cm,between origins} , row sep = {1cm , between origins}]
{
& John \\ Doe    &      & \\
&        &     &\\
};

\draw[->] (a-1-1) -- (a-2-1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: Thanks for updating your code. What's stopping you from inserting text between the `&`s?

Comment: You might want to change your question title into something like "How to add line breaks in TikZ matrix of nodes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give your nodes a fixed with, you can add line breaks. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(a)[
  matrix of nodes, 
  nodes in empty cells, 
  nodes={draw, circle, align=center, text width=0.8cm},
  column sep={1.5cm, between origins}, 
  row sep={1.5cm, between origins}
]{
  & John \linebreak Doe & & \\
  & & &\\
};

\draw[->] (a-1-1) -- (a-2-1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what did you change in my code?

Comment: except adding \linebreak between John and Doe?

Comment: @DanielDeWet I gave the nodes a fixed width

Comment: Why did this cause the linebreak to "work"?